# Best way to share ActiveRecord models and data between different Rails Apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeresource

I have several rails applications that will use the same core set of Models and data, for example:

- Apps
- Developers
- Categories

Each app builds on top of this core data and uses it in different ways. For example, I might have something like this in another app:

- **Activity**
- **Users**
- *Apps (shared)*
- *Developers (shared)*
- *Categories (shared)*

What is the best way to share the Models **and** data between them? The Apps, Developers and Category data will all be the same for every app so I would rather not have to duplicate the data in every app's database.

**EDIT:** I'm thinking through a couple of possible solutions:

- Rails engines (would solve the duplicate Models in different apps problem, but not the shared data issue)
- Using ActiveResource to access the core data (solves the shared data, but not the shared model issue)

Comment: In your first possible solution, is sharing data a problem because each app are deployed to a different server?

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, but from what I remember, yes that was the issue. Each rails app was on a different server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a shared database to solve the shared data problem between heroku and a server on EC2 which does some background processing I can't do on heroku.  In my case I'm using the same application, but really all I'm doing is using delayed_job on the EC2, so I'm only using the models from the app there.  If I were going to use them in another application, I would probably go through the trouble of creating a gem to use between them.

Comment: Interesting... I actually need to do something very similar. (I'm using Heroku as well.) By shared database do you mean one _other_ than the Heroku one? In my case, I need to breakout the core stuff right away, but I hadn't thought about using a gem to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I hosted the database with Amazon RDS, my app on heroku talks to that.  About two weeks later heroku came out with their postgresql add-on (http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/11/10/heroku_postgresql/) which would have also worked for me.  Probably would have preferred it actually, but c'est la vie.