# how do i share common models among many projects in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 2 different rails project, and I want to share my models among them.  How could I achieve this?

I am considering a gem or sub-modules.

Comment: Personally, I'd factor them out into a gem or engine. If you want a more detailed explanation, I'll expound this into a full answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the common code to a gem, or at the very least into a library structure (maybe in /lib ...) that you can isolate and manually include into your two projects.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose when you say share models, you imply `activerecord` models. You can create symlink to folder. Or something similar has been asked at [Share Models between 2 Rails API's (Separate Applications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487805/share-models-between-2-rails-apis-separate-applications)